# Retrieving only some part/values of entity from JPA query(Spring boot + MySQL)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing JPA queries for some project and I don't need whole entity from database. So, how can I get only few field values of entity from JPA?

For example, suppose I have User entity with userId, username, password, dateOfBirth, address and some other fields. So what I want is to return only username and password and no other details. So, how to achieve this in JPA Spring boot with MySQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA and Spring Data support this, it is called projection ([like this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections))